# Execute JavaScript code every time table changes

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a table that loads data in an asynchronous way and I want to be able to execute a function every time the content on it changes (whether it is new data or changes to the current).

I would like to know if there is a way to execute that code, or maybe listen to an event that would help me. I'm using Typescript, or in this case I can use JavaScript, but not libraries like JQuery.

I would also accept only being able to execute the code if the number of rows changes, but I would prefer to execute it each time some data changes.

If anybody can help me with this I would appreciate it so much!

Comment: have u tried event listener change ?

Comment: What table, what function, what code? _Why tell when you can show?_ :)

Answer (score -1):

You can add event listeners to your cells like this for click:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td')
.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
}));
```

Comment: The question says "every time the content on it changes" not "when the table cell is clicked"